# What's the brightness depth of IPhone 5 camera in bits?

Tags: iphone, bit-depth, color-depth

Likely this will be the same as the color depth in bits per channel.

For digital cameras it can be 8bit or 12bit and sometimes as high as 14bit. What is it for the IPhone 5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For all intents and purposes, that would be 8-bits per channel or 24-bit per pixels** because what you get out from the camera is a JPEG image and that is its limit.

The sensor internally is *highly likely* to have a greater bit-depth, maybe 10 or 12 bits per channel. This is actually needed to produce an 8-bit-per-channel JPEG because sensor output is linear but JPEG levels follow a gamma curve. If you have an 8-bit linear sensor, you would not be able to fill out all possible values of a JPEG image.

Comment: The discreet brightness (color) values of a JPEG image are not linearly spaced in brightness? I presume they are and the difference between the scales exists to make the image look correct as a photo. Also, can other apps not get the data more directly, or is this built in at a hardware or OS level to only provide an already constructed JPEG?

Comment: Sorry, just after a little more info then I'll mark as correct, it's a good answer.

Comment: They are *not* supposed to be linearly spaced in a JPEG. If someone were to produce a JPEG with linear values, it would look wrong. Apple does not give direct access to the hardware. That is probably to abstract the differences between cameras so that software that use it can work with future generations of iPhones.

Comment: @alan2here Just to clarify, the *brightness* values are not linearly spaced. It has been a while since I wrote a JPEG encoder but I *believe* color (hue/saturation) is in its internal representation.

Comment: Thanks. I've never noticed working with JPEG files in image editors, they seem just to have linear 8bit per channel color, then add lossy compression. It's interesting that internally things are different.

Comment: So can other apps get at all 12 or 14 bits per channel, or does everything get given a JPEG?

Comment: No. No app gets more than 8 bits per channel. As I said, there is no information on the internal linear read out and Apple has good reasons not to expose that information.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks again, I couldn't find this information elsewhere, your super helpful.